# console.log does not work onclick event when the files are in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, xampp

I want to display data in the `console.log()` when a button is clicked . so my code is

```js
  let btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('button clicked !!')
        })
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">click</button>
```

This code works fine as expected , But When open the file from  the local host XAMPP ; the data is not displayed on the console , i tried to use `alert()` instead , it woks fine , i tried also to move the console.log('clicked!!') outside the event callback function , it woks fine also!! but as long as it is inside the function it does not work on the click event .

here is a i recorder for better understanding => https://youtu.be/6xYowU8l7hM

Comment: The only reason could be if the code doesn't bind the event properly, or if there's a JS error earlier on which prevents it from executing - but you would have a console error about that. Just being on localhost is not the cause of this alone, it would be some difference between the code or html in the two environments

Comment: here is a i recorder for better understanding => https://youtu.be/6xYowU8l7hM

Comment: Your URL is wrong. It should be `localhost://test`

Comment: the url is correct 1 => it returns the page recquired 2=> i have tested yours , there is no error in the url

Comment: I see you are also using Firebug Lite, can you check that inspector?

Comment: From the video it looks like maybe the loading of the button is delayed somehow which might cause the binding to fail. But it's not clear why entirely. Please post a [mre] here in the question. The code you've shown here is insufficient to recreate the issue

Comment: i tried firebug and it is working on it i tried on Edge browser too and it is working  . but why it is not working on google chrome console when on xampp?

Comment: Try disabling Firebug Lite in Chrome

Comment: have disabled it and it is working now , Thank You !!. is there any explaination of why this is happening ?

Comment: You'd really have to step through things to see what that plugin is doing, and if you aren't using it, I'd just leave it off and move on. Modern Chrome has really good set of debugging tools.

Comment: I have been using it for DOM debugging for a while . i have removed it now , Thank You so much !! <3